# How to switch between Serilog and another logger in .Net Core through configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I need to be able to switch between Serilog and another logger, MyLog. Currently I am switching by comment/uncomment code as the following:

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            //// === to switch between Serilog and MyLogger comment/uncomment code below ===
            //.UseSerilog((hostContext, loggerConfig) =>
            //    loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostContext.Configuration));
            .ConfigureLogging((hostBuilderContext, logging) =>
             {
                 logging.AddMyLogger(options =>
                 {
hostBuilderContext.Configuration.GetSection(MyLoggerOptions.LogOptions).Bind(options);
                 });
             });
}
```

This works, but I prefer to make it controlled by a appsettings.json setting, say, Logger. So here is my appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "Logger": "Serilog", // Use Serilog or MyLog

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Grpc": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "MyLog": {
      "Options": {
        "FolderPath": "logs",
        "FilePath": "Svr_{date}.log"
      },
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Error"
      }
    }
  },

  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console "
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "Logs\\Serilog_Server-.log",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

and here is the code where I try to set log depending on the Loger setting:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })

        .ConfigureLogging((hostBuilderContext, logging) =>
        {
            string loger = hostBuilderContext.Configuration.GetValue<String>("Logger");
            if (loger == "MyLog")
            {
                logging.AddMyLogger(options =>
                {
                    hostBuilderContext.Configuration.GetSection(MyLoggerOptions.LogOptions).Bind(options);
                });
            }
            else if (loger == "Serilog")
            {
                logging.AddSerilog(); // here is the problem. Serilog doesn't write.
            }
        });
```

The problem of this code is the Serilog (MyLog is fine) - it doesn't write at all. My guess is that, since I don't have a way to pass in the configuration object, it might not get configured properly. But how do I fix it? or is there a better way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Tried what Camilo suggested as the following with an error. How do I get the configuration object from here?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this in your Startup Class, in the Startup constructor: 
`Configuration = builder.Build();`
where Configuration is set as `public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }`